# Converting POST data to GET

Tags: php

I want to output make is required as flash message,Once the page is refreshed previous error messages should totally vanish ,but it is not happening what's wrong Here.
I am at auto.php and still want to be at the page with messages, but when page is refreshed all the messages should disappear.

```
if (!empty($_POST['make']) && !empty($_POST['year']) && !empty($_POST['mileage'])) {
    if (is_numeric($_POST['year']) && is_numeric($_POST['mileage'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO autos (make,year, mileage)  VALUES (:make, :year, :mileage)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':make' => $_POST['make'],
            ':year' => $_POST['year'],
            ':mileage' => $_POST['mileage']));
        $_SESSION["success"] = "Record added";
        header("Location:addnew.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['errors'] = "Mileage and year must be numeric";
        // header("Location:auto.php");
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['errors'] = "make is required";
    // header("Location:auto.php");
}
```

Code in View controller is:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
    echo('<p style="color:green">' . $_SESSION["success"] . "</p>\n");
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
} else {
    echo('<p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION["errors"] . "</p>\n");
    // header("Location:auto.php");
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
```

Comment: so  you are saying after submitting it, it should give you a clean page with success or error, right !!!

Comment: i am saying "without sucess or error",i just need a blank page with the forms

Comment: uncomment your // header("Location:auto.php"), then run the code

Comment: the page stucks and says too many redirects

Comment: i see the error,  make a parent  ---- if for all like if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){   ///your code here  }

Comment: Can U make it more clear? I didn't get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use always  put POST REQUEST code in a post request block like below:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
   if (!empty($_POST['make']) && !empty($_POST['year']) && !empty($_POST['mileage'])) {
    if (is_numeric($_POST['year']) && is_numeric($_POST['mileage'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO autos (make,year, mileage)  VALUES (:make, :year, :mileage)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':make' => $_POST['make'],
            ':year' => $_POST['year'],
            ':mileage' => $_POST['mileage']));
        $_SESSION["success"] = "Record added";
        header("Location:addnew.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['errors'] = "Mileage and year must be numeric";
         header("Location:auto.php");
    }
  } else {
    $_SESSION['errors'] = "make is required";
     header("Location:auto.php");
  }
}
```

```
if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
    echo('<p style="color:green">' . $_SESSION["success"] . "</p>\n");
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
} else if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])){
    echo('<p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION["errors"] . "</p>\n");
    // header("Location:auto.php");
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
```

Comment: Now I am not getting error message "make is required"

Comment: print your post request to check , if there is make index available or not

Comment: This code would stop the redirected many times problem

Comment: actually i am recieving a undefined index: error for this line of code                                           echo('<p style="color:red">' . $_SESSION["errors"] . "</p>\n");

Comment: your form is not sending make index, check your client side

Comment: Thank You for Your time,Helped me a lot